# Bind this to the youtube api statechange

Tags: backbone.js, youtube-api, requirejs

I have a question about 'this' when using the youtube player javascript api in a require.js and backbone app. The youtube iframe_api is being loaded in a require.js module which I'm not including below. Here's my code, which is all following the typical backbone extend layout for a view.

```
    youTubePlayer: function() {
        var player,
            self = this,
            i = 0;

        self.videoArray = [];

        if ($('.slidevideo').length) {
            _.each($('.slidevideo'), function(el, i) {
                var YTid = $(el).data('videoid');

                self.player = new YT.Player('Player-' + YTid, {
                    videoId: YTid,
                    playerVars: {
                        enablejsapi: 1
                    }
                });

                self.videoArray.push(self.player);
            });
        };

        setTimeout(function(){
            _.each(self.videoArray, function(video) {

                video.addEventListener("onStateChange", self.stateChange)

            });

        }, 5000);
    },
    stateChange: function(e){
        console.log(e);
                    console.log(this);
    }
```

The issue is that 'this' in the stateChange function loses it's reference to the backbone view and instead references the global window object where I've loaded the youtube API and the YT constructor. How do I keep 'this' scoped within the Backbone view? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind):

```
video.addEventListener("onStateChange", _.bind(self.stateChange, self));
```